# Cannot assign value of type '[ViewController.Variable_Name]' to type '[String]'

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to pass an array to another `UIViewController` but get this error:

```
Cannot assign value of type '[ViewController.Lugares]' to type '[String]'
```

for this line of code

```
    if(Array[0]=="Lahua Park"){
       //send me to that location 
    }
```

**First View Controller:**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate,  UITableViewDataSource {

    ...

    var fetchedCountry = [Lugares]()

    class Lugares{
        var lugares : String

        init(lugares: String){
            self.lugares = lugares
        }
    }

    ...

     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let secondController = segue.destination as! SecondController

        secondController.transferPaises = fetchedCountry (Error Ocurrs)
    }
```

**Second View Contoller:**

```
class SecondController: UIViewController {

var transferPaises = Array<String>()

..

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    if (transferPaises[0]=="Mexico") {
        print(transferPaises)

            location.latitude = 19.432608
            location.longitude = -99.133209
            let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location, span: span)

            map.setRegion(region, animated: true)

        }

    ....

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make this a public class declared outside your `UIViewController`

```
public class Lugares{
        var lugares : String

        init(lugares: String){
            self.lugares = lugares
        }
}
```

Also, change `transferPaises` to match `fetchedCountry` type

```
var transferPaises = [Lugares]()
```

Comment: It worked but not exactly when i compare in the second view controller it prints [lista.Lugares]
[lista.Lugares, lista.Lugares]
[lista.Lugares, lista.Lugares, lista.Lugares] instead of the name of the place(lugar)

Comment: How are you printing it?

Comment: print(fetchedCountry) (so i can check what it is sending)

Comment: To check what it's sending, try using a breakpoint at that line and inspecting from the bottom left bar. Also, print(fetchedCountry) just print outs the object name. Since this is a custom array you'll have to do a for loop and print out `lugares` value for each item.

Comment: "Since this is a custom array you'll have to do a for loop and print out lugares value for each item",how?

Comment: for item in transferPaises {
     print(item.lugares)
}

Answer (score 0):

`transferPaises` is an array of Strings

```
var transferPaises = Array<String>()
```

`fetchedCountry` is ***NOT*** an array of strings:

```
var fetchedCountry = [Lugares]()
```

so, you cannot assign an array of type `Lugares` to an array of type `String`

Comment: So,any solutions?

Comment: Either make `transferPaises` an array of `Lugares` or create an array of String from your array of `Lugares` and pass *that* array.

Comment: Can you explain me with code, please i really don't understand parsing from Lugares to an Array, (Mostly im coding blindly)